# Is there a way to check if input value includes specific keyCodes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, keycode

I have an array of keyCodes and I need to check if any of the characters in a textarea isn't included in that array. While it would be quite easy to check if key pressed is in the array unfortunately it wouldn't work if let's say the text is pasted in the textarea.

This is so my character limit on the text area changes if a character with a keyCode exists in the text area that's not in the array. For example if the keyCode for š (83) isn't in the array and it would change the character limit based on that.

```
 dec_codes=[10, 12, 13, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,...]
```

I don't know what other code to provide.

And yes I know it would be much better for checking if the array was characters instead of keyCodes, but the array was provided for me and I'm just wondering if I can achieve what I need without having to convert the array.

Comment: Post your code. You can use onchange event, it will work when content is pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can listen for any input in textarea and compare its text's splitted version to your char codes, charCodeAt and some methods are very helpfull here e.g.

```
function checker(charCodes, text) {
    return text.split().some(char => charCodes.indexOf(char.charCodeAt(0)) > -1);
}


textareaNode.addEventListener('input', event => {
    if(checker([101,105], event.target.value)){
        // char code exists
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if any of the character from given array is in the string.

```js
const charCodes = [10, 12, 13, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42].reduce((acc, x) => Object.assign({}, acc, {[String.fromCharCode(x)]: true}), {});

const hasChars = (source, charCodes) => {
  let len = source.length;
  
  while (len--) {
    if (source.charAt(len) in charCodes) {
      return true;
    }
  }
    
  return false;
}

console.log(hasChars("hello", charCodes))
console.log(hasChars("\nhello", charCodes))
console.log(hasChars("hel)o", charCodes))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of paste and keypress event. Paste to handle the ctrl + v (pasting) of content.

To test type `*` or copy-paste `*****` or copy-pate `*h*e*l*l*o* **wo**rl**d**` where `*` has a keyCode of 42 and   (space) has a keyCode of 32.

```js
const ta = document.getElementById("ta");
const dec_codes = [10, 12, 13, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42]

ta.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.value += filterInput(e.key);
});

ta.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.value += filterInput(e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))
});

const filterInput = data => {
  return data.split("").filter(char => {
    return dec_codes.findIndex(code=> char.charCodeAt() === code) === -1
  }).join("");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```